# margin and layout in android

Tags: android, xml, layout

I want to create card like -

[image: pictures],

I try to use `margin`, but not win with this idea. I try create for all element personal view and use `padding` or `margin` but I not have result.

I have code like that

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rlCardBlock"
        style="@style/Widget.CardContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="title"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/title"
            android:maxLines="5"
            android:text="content" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_more_vert_black_36dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Thank you for your attentions.

Comment: i dont know how create space like in image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android already have pre defined widgets for card and recycler view. You may use the android cardview and recycler view for your problem, it quiet easy for you to implement.

For this 
You first add dependencies if you are using android studio as IDE

```
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.+'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.+'
```

then in your above metioned code change it into

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp"
    >

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/cv"
        >



<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/rlCardBlock"
style="@style/Widget.CardContent"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:maxLines="2"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="title"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/title"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:maxLines="5"
    android:text="content" />

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/description"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:maxLines="5"
    android:text="content" />

<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/rlCardBlock"
style="@style/Widget.CardContent"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<Button
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="Action 1"
  android:id="@+id/button1"
  />

 <Button
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="Action 2"
  android:id="@+id/button2"
  />

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

here is the tutorial : [link](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-recyclerview-and-cardview-on-android--cms-23465)

Comment: i use cardview and recycler view, question  - how i can make space beetween element in my card, like in  my image

Comment: space means padding?

Comment: @sharpsolutions Do you need the absolute layout which you show in the picture. Am i right

Comment: yes, padding or margin, how i can make margin or padding between that 2 element? title and content. if i use layout_marginTop or bottom his made margin relatively rlCardBlock

Comment: Now check the code which is the layout the picture you have shown

Comment: ok, great) that help me. Need just change Relative to Liner. With Relative we can't use margin in my case.

Answer (score 1):

On title use `android:layout_marginTop="22dp"`
On subtitle `use android:layout_marginTop="12dp"`
On text use `android:layout_margin="16dp"`

But, you may choose other ways, either padding or margin